# Autohotkey: How to map a keystroke to a controller button press

Tags: controllers, autohotkey

I have a dualshock 4, and I know how to remap a controller button to a key, for example 'Joy2::v'. But I can't figure out how to do it the other way around. I would like to have a command like 'v::Joy2' but this just gives an error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't recommend using AutoHotKey for a DualShock 4 on Windows. [DS4Windows](https://github.com/Ryochan7/DS4Windows) is a very good alternative that emulates an Xbox 360 controller, so any game with native XInput support will be able to use the DS4.

Comment: @Lemon I don't want to use the DS4, I want to emulate it with my keyboard. You are describing the opposite of what I want to do

Comment: DS4Windows also allows you to bind individual buttons to keys. I forgot to mention that. Is better than using the DS4 as-is because it also allows you to bind  individual sections of the touchpad,